# Returning Periodic Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table full of information for various times of the day but I want to pull data for each item on a half hour cycle. I have wrote the following piece of SQL to pull back the information for every half hour but there is a problem with it and I can't seem to rectify it!

```
AND DATEPART(minute, MyTimestamp) in (0, 30)
```

At first this seemed to work just fine but when I actually looked at the information in more detail I realized that it was returning data for the following times:

```
00:00:00
00:00:30
00:30:00
00:30:30
```

But in reality it should be only returning these times:

```
00:00:00
00:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The minute part of `00:00:30` is `0` so its returned, to eliminate non-zero seconds add another clause:

```
where DATEPART(minute, MyTimestamp) in (0, 30) 
  and DATEPART(second, MyTimestamp) = 0
```

or only include times with seconds modulo 30 mins;

```
where datediff(second, cast(MyTimestamp as date), MyTimestamp) % 1800 = 0
```

Comment: thanks very much for your answer! I am not in front of my computer at the moment but I will try it as soon as I can and let you know the outcome then!

Answer (score 0):

Are you guaranteed to have an entry exactly on the hour and exactly on the half-hour? You're concerned about the entry that comes in 30 seconds after the (half-)hour but what if that is the first entry of that time frame?

Here is a solution that divides the entries into half-hour segments and then selects the first (earliest) entry of each segment.

First I had to gen up some sample data. I used the old standby, AdventureWorks. The Sales.SalesOrderHeader table has an OrderDate field that would fit the bill, but it has no time values. So let's supply some. I picked the first day of data and used it to create a test table in <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227fe/0)</kbd> using random values to fill in some hour, minute and second values.

There are plenty of entries on that one day. Let's look at the raw data: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227fe/1)</kbd>

```
ID          OrderDate
----------- -----------------------
43684       2011-05-31 01:14:05.000
43673       2011-05-31 01:20:41.000
43674       2011-05-31 01:40:22.000
43681       2011-05-31 02:00:32.000
...
43688       2011-05-31 20:18:45.000
43672       2011-05-31 21:49:50.000
43693       2011-05-31 22:46:08.000
43670       2011-05-31 23:14:22.000

(43 row(s) affected)
```

Now let's separate each timestamp into half-hour segments: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227fe/2)</kbd>

```
ID          OrderDate               Hour        HalfHour
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
43684       2011-05-31 01:14:05.000 1           0
43673       2011-05-31 01:20:41.000 1           0
43674       2011-05-31 01:40:22.000 1           1
43681       2011-05-31 02:00:32.000 2           0
....
43688       2011-05-31 20:18:45.000 20          0
43672       2011-05-31 21:49:50.000 21          1
43693       2011-05-31 22:46:08.000 22          1
43670       2011-05-31 23:14:22.000 23          0

(43 row(s) affected)
```

Now we can group by the Hour and HalfHour fields and take the earliest timestamp of each period: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227fe/5)</kbd>

```
Hour        HalfHour    MinDate
----------- ----------- -----------------------
1           0           2011-05-31 01:14:05.000
1           1           2011-05-31 01:40:22.000
2           0           2011-05-31 02:00:32.000
3           1           2011-05-31 03:56:33.000
....
20          0           2011-05-31 20:18:45.000
21          1           2011-05-31 21:49:50.000
22          1           2011-05-31 22:46:08.000
23          0           2011-05-31 23:14:22.000

(30 row(s) affected)
```

That's all we need to complete the task. Join one result set with the other to get the first entry of each half-hour segment: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/227fe/4)</kbd>.

Here is the final query. It's not exactly what you will find at SQL Fiddle -- it is the one that uses the AdventureWorks database (if you have that database installed and SQL Fiddle is having one of its periodic hissy fits). If you use AdventureWorks, remember to load values into the time portion of the OrderDate field. Also, note that this is written for a single day. To work for time frames longer than one day, you will have to group by day as well as hour and half-hour.

```
with
ByHalfHour as(
    select  soh.SalesOrderID ID, soh.OrderDate,
            DatePart( HOUR, soh.OrderDate ) as Hour,
            Case when DatePart( MINUTE, soh.OrderDate ) < 30 then 0 else 1 end as HalfHour
    from    Sales.SalesOrderheader soh
    where   soh.OrderDate >= '2011-05-31'
        and soh.OrderDate < '2011-06-01'
),
MinHalfHour as(
    select  Hour, HalfHour, Min( OrderDate ) as MinDate
    from    ByHalfHour
    group by Hour, HalfHour
)
select  bhh.*
from    ByHalfHour  bhh
join    MinHalfHour mhh
    on  mhh.Hour    = bhh.Hour
    and mhh.HalfHour= bhh.HalfHour
    and mhh.MinDate = bhh.OrderDate
order by bhh.Hour, bhh.HalfHour;
```